# How to import esri-leaflet into angular using es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

I have imported an esri-leaflet to my angular component.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';  
declare module 'leaflet' {
    ...
}
export = L.esri;
```

And imported:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'esri-leaflet';
```

But when debugging, `console.log(L.esri);` is equal to `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the typings file of esri-leaflet. Check [here](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/1007)

to overcome this import `esri-leaflet` like:

```
import * as esri from "esri-leaflet";
```

and then access the `esri class` like this:

```
console.log(esri);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4m13jqw4)